# Invisible area (size and position of notifications) prevents interaction with any windows/menus

Tags: mouse, notifications, click

After some time it occurs that i have a non-interact able area on my elementary OS Freya desktop.
The problem is demonstrated in a short video with indicating mouse clicks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW45zqfAFGM

Even all menus in this area with the size of an "invisible notification" are not interact able, so all the panel menus are useless at this point when the bug occurs. Once the bug shows up it stays until reboot.

Which logs or any other stuff shall i provide to fix this issue with your help?

EDIT: already reported and stated as "in progress":https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1376382

Comment: You use ppa:elementary-os/staging?